# For a pure Windows project, why would I possibly want automatic line end mutilations?

Tags: .net, windows, git, core.autocrlf

As the title says.

All devs for this project are on windows. The software is going to run on windows. Why would I set autocrlf to true?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't, as stated in the [doc](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace)

> If you’re a Windows programmer doing a Windows-only project, then you can turn off this functionality, recording the carriage returns in the repository by setting the config value to false

Answer (score 0):

The reason is to ensure that your line endings are consistent. If you're using Windows tools, generally, you should expect that your line endings are CRLF but there are a lot of ways LF endings could be introduced.

Comment: In my experience GIT has been the biggest culprit in that regard.